# Google indexing/search results multilingual

Tags: internationalization, seo

We have a multilingual application that can use GET parameters to distringuish between different language versions as well as the client's browser language. If the language is not supported or unknown, we use English as a fallback. Currently supported languages are English and German, btw.

Thus, a visitor with browser language 'en' (any other like 'es', 'zh' etc. - except 'de' - would result in English as described) would get the following language versions for the different urls:

- mydomain.com --> english version
- mydomain.com?language=en --> english version
- mydomain.com?language=de --> german version

This works so far but here's the problem we have with the Google index:

When we search for the site from Germany or using google.de, one (at least our customer) would expect to get the results in German.

However, Google displays the results (the page excerpt/meta description) using the english text instead of the German text.

Example, searching for "mydomain" (please excuse the programmer art :) ):

```
My Domain Title
http://www.mydomain.com
Here's the english meta description even if we search from Germany.
```

The problem seems to be that GoogleBot either uses English or doesn't provide any language information (which I think is the case) and thus gets the English version for "mydomain.com".

We tried to help GoogleBot and put "alternate" links into the page headers, i.e. for "mydomain.com" we'd have those

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.mydomain.com?language=en" /> 
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.mydomain.com?language=de" />
```

However, although theoretically (as far as we understand this) GoogleBot should now know about the different language versions of that page, yet it still returns English results.

We also thought about using the "canonical" tag but wouldn't that mean we'd have to select one single language version for being indexed?

Our ultimate goal would be to have Google return the English version of the page for international user and the German version for the German users.

Any hints on how we could achieve that?

**Update:**

Here's what we did so far to tackle the problem.

First of all, we moved the language into the site's path and whenever the language is missing, we assume German.

Thus we have this result:

```
http://www.mydomain.com --> 301 to "http://www.mydomain.com/de/"
http://www.mydomain.com/de/ --> German, alternatives are "http://www.mydomain.com/de/" and "http://www.mydomain.com/en/"
http://www.mydomain.com/en/ --> English, alternatives are "http://www.mydomain.com/de/" and "http://www.mydomain.com/en/"
```

German Google now displays the German results as expected, however English Google (or German Google set up to display English results) also shows German results. I assume the reason is either a mistake in the redirect or Google doesn't really care.

Comment: Does the English version of the site link to the German version with plain HTML links?

Comment: It does but only via the language change link, which is the same url as the page's just differing in the language parameter. Every other link should link to the same language version.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it by using the **language restrict** (lr) parameter, as explained in the [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results?hl=en#lrsp)

Hope this helps.

Clarification: This helps in Google Site Search (which we're using). However, normal Google searches via google.com still return those ugly mixed language results.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but if I understand the description correctly this is a search parameter, right? If so, we can't rely on that, since we don't know whether site search or normal google.com are used.

Comment: yeah sorry. I found your question while trying to solve my own problem which was unwanted multi-language results in our Google Site Search (formerly known as Google Custom Search).
However, some test with Google.com in English and Google.fr in French (our site is German, English and French) showed me that the problem with English results showing up inbetween the German ones is a mere german problem. And thinking of it, this is what I as a regular german web surfer would expect - the most relevant search results in my mother tongue, followed by the most relevant ones in English.

Comment: tl;dr google correctly recognized your pages' language, but serves the user alternative languages as well unless he customizes his google search settings

Comment: I'll look into it. I would also expect to get English results when using German Google, depending on the search term. In our case however, we have the same page in different languages and thus we'd expect to get the correct result. I'll update the question with what we did so far, but now we seem to get German results in English Google - however, I have a feeling of why this is happening.